# Where does the phrase "Shamaitsa Aliba D’Hilchasa" come from?

Tags: halacha, torah-study

Recently I’ve come across the phrase:

> Shamaitsa Aliba D’Hilchasa

What does this mean, and more specifically, where does it come from (Shas, Poskim?)

Answer (score 6):

The phrase crops up a few times in Shas, including [Yoma 26a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.26a.6?lang=bi):

> אמר רבא לא משכחת צורבא מרבנן דמורי אלא דאתי משבט לוי או משבט יששכר לוי דכתיב יורו משפטיך ליעקב יששכר, דכתיב (ובני) יששכר יודעי בינה לעתים לדעת מה יעשה ישראל ואימא יהודה נמי דכתיב יהודה מחוקקי **אסוקי שמעתא אליבא דהילכתא** קאמינא
>
> Rava said: You do not find a young Torah scholar who gives halakhic instruction unless he comes from the tribe of Levi or from the tribe of Issachar. The assertion with regard to the tribe of Levi is as it is written: “They shall teach Jacob Your ordinances and Israel Your law” (Deuteronomy 33:10). And the assertion with regard to the tribe of Issachar is as it is written: “And of the children of Issachar, men that had understanding of the times, to know what Israel should do” (I Chronicles 12:33). The Gemara asks: And say that scholars come from the tribe of Judah also, as it is written: “Judah is my lawgiver” (Psalms 60:9). Rava answers: While it is true that the tribe of Judah also taught Torah, in my statement I was speaking only of those who can **draw conclusions according to the halakha**.
>
> (*Translation from sefaria.org*)